# Font formatting order

Tags: fonts, formatting, best-practices

I want to set my `chapterprefix` font for `scrbook` class.  This is what I want to do:

```
\setkomafont{chapterprefix}{\centering\Huge\rmfamily\mdseries\scshape}
```

However, as I was writting it, I asked myself if there is any difference in the order I give `LaTeX` the commands.  Is there any **right** order to do this?  Should I go first with the placement (`\centering`), with the family (`\rmfamily`), shape (`\scshape`), weight (`\mdseries`), size (`\Huge`)...?

Comment: Order is only important when elements may affect one another. However, your choices are mutually exclusive and doesn't influence the other.

Comment: Note that this was one of the advances in LaTeX 2e. Those font selection commands are all part of the New Font Selection Scheme and the major improvement this scheme brought was that the different aspects of fonts could be selected independently so that \mdseries, for example, does not affect the shape or family and \scshape does not affect the weight etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The new font selection scheme (NFSS) that became the standard with LaTeX2e identifies a font along 4 orthogonal axes (or rather 5 if you also count font encoding):

- font family (via commands like `\rmfamily`, `\sffamily`, etc. or via the more general `\fontfamily{<name>}\selectfont`)
- font series, which is a combination of weight and width, e.g., "bold extended" as in `\bfseries` etc or the more general `\fontseries{<name>}\selectfont`
- font shape, which is something like "normal", italics, but also "small caps" (which isn't quite right, see below). Commands are `\itshape`, `\scshape`, etc., or the more general `\fontshape{<name>}\selectfont`
- font size which is covered by `\small`, `\large`, etc or the more general `\fontsize{<size>}{<baselineskip>}\selectfont`

If a selection on one of these axes is change the others will not be altered so in that respect the order is irrelevant.

However there are some things to take into consideration:

- If a set of high-level commands such as `\rmfamily \scshape \mdseries \Huge` is executed one after another then each of them internally issues a `\selectfont` so that all intermediate selections will actually be loaded.  Depending on the order you give these may be different fonts that are loaded (even if never actually used for typesetting).
- As long as these interim fonts actually exist that doesn't matter much other than unnecessarily loading some fonts). However if any intermediate combination is not available, NFSS will be forced to apply some substituation and depending on the order of commands that substituation may come out differently.
- In general selecting fonts (and even more so loading them) takes time, so for  style setups it can be more efficient to use the more generic low-level commands followed by a single `\selectfont`. E.g., you example could be written as

  `\fontfamily{\rmdefault}\fontshape{\scdefault}\fontseries{\mddefault}\Huge`

  with the `\Huge` issuing finally the `\selectfont`. Or it could be done with explicit names if you want some really specific font, e.g.,

  `\fontfamily{cmr}\fontshape{sc}\fontseries{md}\fontsize{24pt}{30pt}\selectfont`

In fact there is also a `\usefont` command which lets you set encoding, family, series, shape in one go (size needs to be specified seperately) so that would then be something like

```
\fontsize{24}{30}\usefont{T1}{cmr}{md}{sc}
```